# App.Config escaping

Tags: c#, escaping, app-config

I have this `app.config` which contains `FolderPath` under `AppSettings` node.

During testing, the QAs used the path: `C:\directory\test & test` on `FolderPath`  value that made the application crash on startup.

I know it's the unescaped character (specifically `&`) that made the error.

They're insisting that it's a program error and should be automatically escaped because some users may not know about escaping strings.

How do I deal with it?

Comment: did the QA's add that to the .config? or does you app add it to the config? Because `&` is invalid for Xml, and they should know that.

Comment: @sa_ddam213: The QA's add that intentionally. And they saying it's a program error. And the characters should be escaped automatically.

Comment: if they added it to the Xml themselfs then its NOT a program error, thats called user error, The QA's need to read about `Xml Character and Entity References` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256190.aspx

Comment: Just to be clear, your QA's edited the xml not using your app and are blaming your app?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 They're not actually blaming the program, they're suggesting it should be escaped at the first place, which is impossible (the app.config or any XML don't do automatic escaping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If users are allowed to edit `app.config`, they must write correct XML, period. This is not a program error, and there is frankly nothing you can (or should) do about this. But you already know this.

I believe the point your QAs are trying to make is:

> You should not expect "normal" users to know how to edit/write XML, or even know what XML is. Instead, for user-editable values, you should create a UI which edits the app.config, and otherwise tell your users to leave the file alone unless they "know what they are doing".

Answer (score 0):

> They're insisting that it's a program error and should be automatically escaped because some users may not know about escaping strings.

*User should never be allowed to deal directly with settings file*. If they have to update **they should be provided a GUI** where they can update as necessary. This way you have the *control* to test whether or not the *input is correct or not*.